# find lines containing "^" and replace entire line with ""

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with a string on each line... ie.

```
test.434
test.4343
test.4343t34
test^tests.344
test^34534/test
```

I want to find any line containing a "^" and replace entire line with a blank.

I was trying to use sed:

```
sed -e '/\^/s/*//g' test.file
```

This does not seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/^.*\^.*$//' test.file
```

For example:

```
$ cat test.file
test.434
test.4343
test.4343t34
test^tests.344
test^34534/test
$ sed -e 's/^.*\^.*$//' test.file
test.434
test.4343
test.4343t34


$
```

To delete the offending lines entirely, use

```
$ sed -e '/\^/d' test.file
test.434
test.4343
test.4343t34
```

Comment: Thanks that does work, is there a way to get that to remove the line entirely?  Instead of just replacing it with a blank line?

Comment: Right but, is there a way to do it in one line?  More curiosity sake than to negate your solution... :-)_

Comment: @Chris The second `sed` command operates on the original `test.file` from your question and does its work in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

other ways

awk

```
awk '!/\^/' file
```

bash

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
    *"^"* ) continue;;
    *) echo "$line"
  esac
done <"file"
```

and probably the fastest

```
grep -v "\^" file
```